# Do the vertical bar and semicolon denote the same thing in the context of conditional probability?

Tags: probability, notation

In the [CMU Machine Learning Lecture](https://youtu.be/He_D2KWXyQU?t=3849), likelihood function is denoted by $P(D|\theta)$

In the [Cornell lecture note](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote04.html), likelihood function is denoted by $P(D;\theta)$

are semicolon and vertical bar the same here?

Comment: In this pair of contexts, yes. Technically the semantic implications are a little bit different, in that the former notation is suggestive of conditional probability (what would be the likelihood function you would use if you exactly knew the parameter?) while the latter notation just means that the author is distinguishing between arguments and parameters. But the usage is the same.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/meaning-of-probability-notations-pzd-w-and-pzd-w and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-semicolon-in-fx-theta

Answer (score 20):

Although some writers are a bit sloppy and inconsistent, technically, no, they are not the same.  They are similar, but not quite identical.

The Sheffer stroke (vertical bar) is read "given that" or "contingent upon."  Thus $p(x|y)$ means the probability density of $x$ *given that* some event or state of affairs $y$ has occurred.  For instance if $x$ represents a height in centimeters, the term $p(x|{\rm woman})$ means the probability density we find the height value $x$ *given that* the person we are measuring is a woman.  This is classical terminology of *contingent probability density*.  This use is restricted to probability and statistics.

The semicolon is slightly different, and can apply in cases unrelated to probability and statistics.  Suppose you have a mathematical function that depends upon two (or more) variables, say $f(x,y)$.   Suppose you're primarily interested in the behavior of $f$ based on the value of $x$.  You want to take derivatives with respect to $x$, limits for large and small $x$, count the zeros, and such.  When you write $f(x;y)$ you're in essence creating a new function *OF ONE VARIABLE* ($x$), which we might call $g(x) = f(x;y)$.  This notation recognizes that there is an *implied* or chosen value of $y$ when you examine $g(x)$, but it is not "part of the function."  For instance, it is meaningless to take the derivative of $f(x;y)$ with respect to $y$ any more than it would to take the derivative of $g(x)$ with respect to $y$.  The value of $y$ is a "setting" or a "parameter" that is fixed.

This notative helps avoid confusion when one asks about the intrinsic dimension of a function.

A particularly useful application of this semicolon notation in probability is in the Expectation-Maximization (or EM) Algorithm.  In the algorithm some steps involve the optimization of a function (the expectation) *with respect to one of the many variables*.  It is natural, then, to use $f(x;y)$ during this step to optimize over $x$, where the value of $y$ is fixed and "cannot be touched."

Another use in statistics and pattern recognition is the following.  Suppose you have training data, $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_d$.  You create the dot product with some real-valued weight vector ${\bf w} = \{ w_1, w_2, \ldots , w_d \}$, as in ${\bf w}^t {\bf x} = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \ldots + w_d x_d$.  You want to optimize the value of ${\bf w}$ with respect to some classification.  You create a function $h({\bf w}; {\bf x})$, meaning you can take derivatives with respect to the weights but it makes *NO SENSE* to take a derivative with respect to the data ${\bf x}$, nor is ${\bf w}$ "contingent upon" ${\bf x}$.  Nevertheless, the particular functional form of $h$ has buried behind it the particular values of the data at hand.

Clear?

Comment: The notation for parametric optimization is widely used in a variety of fields. Good answer.

Comment: Excellent answer! Consider the case of MLE in this [CMU Machine Learning Lecture](https://youtu.be/He_D2KWXyQU?t=3849), wrt $\theta$, what notation is preferred? $f(\theta;D)$ ?

Comment: Purely conjectural, but do you think there's a Bayesian-frequentist divide here? If one views model parameters as random variables, then it seems very natural for them to consider likelihoods as conditional distributions, hence the $|$, while if one views them as arbitrary variables, then presumably they'd be drawn to a different notation to explicitly differentiate it from both observations $x$ and from the idea of a conditional distribution...

Comment: Nope.  That's unrelated to the issues at hand.

Comment: So the following statement would be acceptable `f(y | x; z)`. It was taught (incorrectly) that they were interchangeable and so that statement feels wrong.

Comment: A warning about "Sheffer stroke": the vertical bar expressing the conditional is only *typografically* identical to the [symbol used by Sheffer in 1913](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1988701) for the `NAND` operation. Today the bar does not stand for a `NAND`, and the symbol for `NAND` is sometimes an upward arrow, which many texts refer to as "Sheffer's stroke".