# How to interpret $P(z|x, y; k)$ with examples?

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, machine-learning, neural-networks

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421665/do-the-vertical-bar-and-semicolon-denote-the-same-thing-in-the-context-of-condit) and [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-maximum-likelihood-estimation-in-machine-learning/), I am trying to understand what can be meant by $P(z|x, y; k)$ notation. How to interpret this with examples in terms of machine learning?

As I understand, $P(z|x, y)$ used for conditional probability. For examples, z is height, x is gender, y is wealth, k is country. With $P(z|woman, rich)$, we are trying to find the height given the person is woman and rich.

In the first link, $f(x; y)$ says $y$ is chosen or implied value and we are interested in the value of $x$. So as I understand $y$ is fixed like hyperparameter(or input data?) and $x$ is the parameter in terms of neural networks.

In the 2nd link, it says $P(X; h)$ finding $h$ that best explains the data $X$. So $X$ is fixed as input data and $h$ is neural network parameters.

In first link the part after semicolon is fixed, but in second link the part before semicolon is fixed. In both cases the positions are different. How to explain this?

#### Edit

If $x$ is image, $y$ is text caption, $k$ is network parameters like weights and biases and with $z$ we are trying to find if the text caption matches the image. Is it a correct explanation of $P(z|x, y; k)$?

Comment: I would say that mixing both bars and semicolons is incorrect notation and they should not be used together.  Have you actually seen this notation used in a paper or book?  Or are you just curious if it was a possible notation without having actually seen it?  Compare to asking if you can write $\Pr(A\mid B\mid C)$ which is also incorrect notation.

Comment: With regards to $f(x,y)$ and trying to optimize $x$ given a stationary value of $y$ or doing the opposite, trying to optimize $y$ given a stationary value of $x$... both are perfectly reasonable to do for generic functions and more specifically for conditional probabilities as well.  "How to explain this?"  What needs explanation?  It is useful in the one scenario to let the one vary and in the other scenario to let the other vary... simple as that.  Perform the math which answers the question you want answered...

Comment: I am asking mostly out of curiosity, but in the 2nd link mixed vertical bar and semicolon is used. There it is written as, `maximize L(y|X ; h)`.

Comment: "*maximize the output $y$ given the input $X$ given the modeling hypothesis $h$*"  I would have much preferred writing as "*...given the input $X$* **and** *the modeling hypothesis $h$*" and written as $L(y\mid X,h)$.  The punchline here is that both $X$ and $h$ are simultaneously being conditioned upon.  My guess is that they opted to write this way to emphasize the distinction between $X$ and $h$... and notation means whatever the person writing it wants it to mean, so it isn't like it *can't* be used... but I would never use it and can not recommend using it.